# Java Optional with multiple commands and return object

Tags: java, optional-chaining

Attempting to execute multiple commands and return an Object (ResponseEntity) using Optional.ifPresentOrElse

More complex does not work:

```
return ifPresentOrElse(
           repoService.findById(inId),
           i -> {
               i.setStatus(inStatus);
               repoService.save(i);
               ResponseEntity.ok().body(i);
           }, 
           () -> {
               LOG.error("Object not available");
               ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
           });
```

Simpler works but doesn't execute all the commands required:

```
Optional<I> iOptional = repoService.findById(inId);
        
return iOptional.map(i -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(i))
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Is there away to achieve this using Optional functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Optional.map` and `Optional.orElseGet`, like this:

```
var responseEntity = repoService.findById(inId)
  .map(record -> {
    record .setStatus(inStatus);
    repoService.save(record);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(record);
  }).orElseGet(() -> {
    LOG.error("Object not available");
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the signature of `ifPresentOrElse` is:

`public void ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<T> action, Runnable emptyAction)`

means that you can't return the value of this function.

So you are not retuning anything when you call `ResponseEntity.ok().body(i)` or `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()`,
they are just rvalues.

On the other side, the signiture of `map` function is:

`public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`

means that you can return the invocation of the mapper function.